# Kinetic.js: Prevent draggable stage from going off-boundaries

Tags: javascript, animation, kineticjs

I'm trying to make a pan-and-zoom Canvas for use as a minimap in a game. I've set the stage to be draggable so the player can move around with the mouse, as well as move individual objects on the layers of the stage. However, I don't want to be able to drag the stage into the surrounding white space. In other words, I only want to allow panning while zoomed in so you never encounter that white space.  To try and constrain the stage, I've set up a dragBoundFunc:

```
        dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
            return {
                x: (pos.x < 0 ? 0 : pos.x > width ? width : pos.x),
                y: (pos.y < 0 ? 0 : pos.y > height ? height : pos.y)
            };
        }
```

(Full JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Brry/)

I'm encountering two problems:

- Firstly, the canvas is still able to move upwards and to the left.
- Secondly, and more annoyingly, the constraints begin to misbehave when we begin to zoom.
  When you zoom, the constraints don't take this fact into account. So, what if we add the stage offsets?

  ```
          dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
          return {
              x: ((ui.stage.getOffset().x+pos.x) < 0 ? 0 : pos.x > width ? width : pos.x),
              y: ((ui.stage.getOffset().y+pos.y) < 0 ? 0 : pos.y > height ? height : pos.y)
          };
      }
  ```

  (Full JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/2fLCd/)

This is a lot better, but now the view "snaps back" when you go too far. It would be nicer if it just stopped moving in the disallowed direction.

Anyone know how I could fix these issues?

Comment: what you mean "constrain the stage", if your stage alredy has width and height as the window?

Comment: Check out the JSFiddles, you can pan away from the circles into surrounding white space. I only want to allow panning while zoomed in, so you never encounter that white space.

Comment: after fiddling around with these jsfiddles, pun I realize that when you zoom, you aren't really changing the position of the stage, just it's scale. Hence the x,y coords don't really change. What you want to do is calculate those x,y after scaling and disallow them to be greater than 0 in you dragbound function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I integrated the Zynga Scroller functionality with the KineticJS framework to get what I wanted.

[Code in action](http://raegquit.com/beerdude26/Zynga%20Scroller/scroller-master/demo/simpleCanvas.html)

Let's step look at the code, which is an amalgamation of things I found online and wrote myself.

First, we generate the canvas using KineticJS:

```
var width = 700;
var height = 700;
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({});
stage.add(layer);

/* I skipped some circle generation code. */
```

Then, we define some events that fire when dragging and dropping something on the layer. We'll use these to populate a global variable called `somethingIsBeingDraggedInKinetic`. We'll use this variable in the panning code of Zynga Scroller so the entire stage isn't moved around when you're dragging a KineticJS shape.

```
var somethingIsBeingDraggedInKinetic = false;
layer.on('dragstart', function(evt) {
    // get the thing that is being dragged
    var thing = evt.targetNode;
    if( thing )
        somethingIsBeingDraggedInKinetic = true;
  });

layer.on('dragend', function(evt) {
    // get the thing that is being dragged
    var thing = evt.targetNode;
    if( thing )
        somethingIsBeingDraggedInKinetic = false;
  });
```

Next up is the Zynga Scroller initialization code. The Zynga Scroller code handles input and transformations, and then passes on three values to a rendering function: `top`, `left` and `zoom`. These values are perfect for passing on to the KineticJS framework:

```
// Canvas renderer
var render = function(left, top, zoom) {

    // Constrain the stage from going too far to the right
    if( (left + (width / zoom)) > width )
        left = width - (width / zoom );

    // Constrain the stage from going too far to the left
    if( (top + (height / zoom)) > height )
        top = height - (height / zoom );

    stage.setOffset(left, top);
    stage.setScale(zoom);
    stage.draw();
};

// Initialize Scroller
this.scroller = new Scroller(render, {
    zooming: true,
    animating: false,
    bouncing: false,
    locking: false,
    minZoom: 1
});
```

After that, we need to position the Zynga Scroller correctly. I'll admit that this part is a bit of black magic for me. I copied the rest of the code over from the "asset/ui.js" file.

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var rect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
scroller.setPosition(rect.left + container.clientLeft, rect.top + container.clientTop);
scroller.setDimensions(700, 700, width, height);
```

Finally, I copied over the panning code as well, and added some code that checks if the KineticJS framework is moving something:

```
var mousedown = false;

container.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName.match(/input|textarea|select/i)) {
        return;
    }

    scroller.doTouchStart([{
        pageX: e.pageX,
        pageY: e.pageY
    }], e.timeStamp);

    mousedown = true;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (somethingIsBeingDraggedInKinetic)
        return;

    if (!mousedown) {
        return;
    }

    scroller.doTouchMove([{
        pageX: e.pageX,
        pageY: e.pageY
    }], e.timeStamp);

    mousedown = true;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    if (!mousedown) {
        return;
    }

    scroller.doTouchEnd(e.timeStamp);

    mousedown = false;
}, false);
```

Oh, and the zoom handler.

```
container.addEventListener(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1 ? "DOMMouseScroll" :  "mousewheel", function(e) {
    scroller.doMouseZoom(e.detail ? (e.detail * -120) : e.wheelDelta, e.timeStamp, e.pageX, e.pageY);
}, false);
```

This is perfect as a basis for a zoomable map!

Comment: Is this functionality possible in `pinch` event in iPad?